# Is "тройбан" derived from "ебан тремя"?

Tags: этимология, числительные, словообразование

*"Тройбан"* is a slang word for *"три"* (a ruder version of 'three'). There is also a word *"трояк"* (less rude and more common). The affix *"як"* can be attached to some other numerals to make it more informal, e.g. *"двояк"*, *"пятак"*.

But the affix *"бан"* can be found only in the word *"тройбан"*. So, I guess, this word has a special, particular origin. I heard a story that the word *"тройбан"* is derived from *"троебан"*, which, in it's turn, goes from the phrase *"трое ебан"*, i.e. "*ебан тремя"* (literally means 'had sexual intercourse with three persons at once'). But I haven't found any further information about this version.

So, my question is: what is true etymology of that word?

Comment: It's always funny how ad hoc folk etymology is completely nonchalant about creating more questions as it tries to give answers. How could something as ungrammatical as `трое ебан` have possibly existed? And while the double [-jı jı-] succumbing to haplology is plausible, how would it go on to lose the vowel, triggering a quantitative shift in the preceding /о/?

Comment: Down-voted since not true - who on earth says in Russian "трое ебан" о "ебан тремя" - nobody says.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

-бан is an argotic suffix that is used to create word  that is not used in normal/official language as one of purposes of argot itself. See *тройбан, щелбан, дружбан*.

Comment: Speculatively, the ultimate source of that `-бан` might be German loanwords like `кегельбан` and `автобан`, where the opaque *Bahn* following a transparent root came to be perceived merely as a quaint noun-deriving suffix. Whether or not it's true, the augmentative suffix `-ан` (*друган*, etc.) was likely an influence.

Answer (score 9):

Just to prove the previous answers and to disappoint you:**тройбан**. belongs to school argot,
"Словарь русского арго" Елистратова

ЩЕЛБАН, -а, м. Удар, щелчок.
Возм. из шк.; общеупотр. «щелчок» + **арготический суффикс «-бан»** (ср. ДРУЖБАН, **ТРОЙБАН** и т. п.).

Жаргон номиналов в нумизматике

> •  3 - алтын (алтынник) (с 1534 г. до начале XVIII в.) - (по Торговой книге 1670 г. 1 алтын=3 новгородки=6 денег=12 полушек), трешка, трояк, троячок, троечка, трояшка, **тройбан**, треха, трюльник, трюндель, , трынка, трёхкопеечник, трехрублевик, трехрублевка, трешник, трёшница; зелененькая, зеленушка (по цвету купюры 3 рубля царской и СССР)

Answer (score 7):

I believe this word belongs to school slang exclusively. And concerning its roots, it's most probably derived as a pure occasionalism with a pattern similar to *дерибан*, *щелбан* etc.